# Reading from files and comparing their data

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that will read from a file (which I've already created).

The program then has to compare the aforementioned file with another file (which again, I have).

Could someone assist me with this? I've already created the part in which the first file has to be read. Also, I'm using a console application, if that helps.

Comment: What kind of files are you talking about?  Is it structured data or do you just need a line-by-line difference?

Comment: I've tried reading the data in both files, but im not sure how to compare the two

Comment: Oh, they're just text files, so a line-by-line difference.

Comment: And what kind of differences, and how many? Is the first extra space enough as an answer, is it case-sensitive?

Answer (score 1):

A simple Linq approach using [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) which produces the set difference:

```
var file1 = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(path2);
var onlyInFileA = file1.Except(file2);
var onlyInFileB = file2.Except(file1);

foreach(string line in onlyInFileA)
{
    // ...
}
foreach(string line in onlyInFileB)
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that you also could compare case-insensitive. You just have to use the overload of `Except`:

```
var onlyInFileA = file1.Except(file2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible straightforward solution:

```
String[] file1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(path1);
String[] file2Lines = File.ReadAllLines(path2);

for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(file1Lines.Length, file2Lines.Length); i++)
{
    if (i > file1Lines.Length)
        /* missing from file 1 */ ;
    else if (i > file2Lines.Length)
        /* missing from file 2); */ ;
    else if (file1Lines[i].Equals(file2Lines[i]))
        /* lines are equal */ ;
    else
        /* lines are different */ ;
}
```